# Protractor test a bootstrap modal - not angular page - timeout

Tags: angular, protractor, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to UI test a bootstrap modal which has not used an angular plugin, it is a vanilla bootstrap modal. I get this error:

> Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish
>   after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an
>   Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details:
>   https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
>   While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector,
>   h2.modal-title)✗

Is there a workaround for this or is it not possible to test a vanilla bootstrap modal with protractor?

Here is my full test:

```
import { browser, element, by, By, $, $$, ExpectedConditions } from 'protractor';
import { E2EUtilities } from './utilities.spec'

    describe('Result Details', function () {
       it(`Shows result details modal when clicking on a result`, function () {
          E2EUtilities.navigateToResultsPage();
          element(by.id('result0')).isPresent().then(function (result) {
             if (result) {
                element(by.id('result0')).click();
                browser.sleep(3000);
                expect(element(by.css('h2.modal-title')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
             } else {
                expect(element(by.css('h2.modal-title')).isPresent()).toBe(false);
             }
          });
       });
    });
```

Please note I have left `E2EUtilities.navigateToResultsPage();` concealed because I know the problem is not with that because The code gets through all that and goes further as can be seen by the eye.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have more luck *turning the synchronization off temporarily*:

```
element(by.id('result0')).isPresent().then(function (result) {
  if (result) {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    element(by.id('result0')).click();
    browser.sleep(3000);  // TODO: use ExpectedConditions?
    expect(element(by.css('h2.modal-title')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
  } else {
    expect(element(by.css('h2.modal-title')).isPresent()).toBe(false);
  }
});

browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
```

Comment: do you know why is this happening? have same issue with only one basic test

Comment: @genuinefafa could be multiple reasons for that - oftentimes it's the use of $timeout in the angular application itself.

Comment: For me it is the `TimerObservable` creating an interval. If i comment this section, the tests run as usually. This is also happening with `setTimeout()`.