# Protractor Timeout - "Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds."

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, protractor, pageobjects

As an e2e tester who has little interaction with the developer, how do I find out what is causing the angularJS website to hang? How do I debug the website and provide them with a tangible solution to my problem? Does Chrome Developer provide an answer to this?

My current solution is to use either of the two code snippets below, but from what I have read, this is not ideal.

```
browser.sleep();
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

I am getting a similar problems to the below:

[Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285341/failed-timed-out-waiting-for-asynchronous-angular-tasks-to-finish-after-11-seco)

> Yes, the most common reason is when application continuously polls
>   $timeout or $http, Protractor will wait indefinitely and time out. But
>   this can also occur in scenarios where App takes more than 11 seconds

[Protractor test a bootstrap modal - not angular page - timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817733/protractor-test-a-bootstrap-modal-not-angular-page-timeout)

> You might have more luck turning the synchronization off temporarily:

Answer (score 1):

The link http://www.protractortest.org/#/debugging would be a good place to start , if you are trying to debug your test run.

The `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` is used in cases when there is a non angular page in between angular pages. Example when there is a non-angular login page before you can navigate to Angular pages. Once you have naviagted from the non-angular page to the angular pages, you would need to set the flage to true i.e. `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;`

`browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` has changed to `browser.waitForAngularEnabled` .

For any timeout related issues , look at http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts

Look at http://www.protractortest.org/#/api for more info.